# How can i hit nextauth sign in with postman?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

Currently i'm trying to create user authentication with NextAuth. I'm able to use it inside my webapp and there is no problem with it. But now, i'm trying to hit the sign in with postman. So i can share the login end point. Here is my `[...nextauth].js`

```
const configuration = {  
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            name: "credentials",
            credentials: {},
            page: "/",
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try
                {   
                    const user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
                        where: {
                            email: credentials.email
                        }
                    });

                    if (user !== null)
                    {
                        const res = await confirmPasswordHash(credentials.password, user.password);
                        if (res === true)
                        {
                           
                      
                            return user;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Hash not matched logging in");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                catch (err)
                {
                    console.log("Authorize error:", err);
                }

            }
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, user, token }) {
            session.user = token.user;
            return session;
          },
       
          async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user;
              }
              return token;
        },
  
    }
}
export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, configuration)
```

When i hit via postman, it is returning HTML view.

```
{
    "email":"myemail@email.com",
    "password":"12345678"
}
```

and the data will hit to `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin`

How can i achieve it ? thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `POST /api/auth/signin/:provider` endpoint instead? See https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#post-apiauthsigninprovider.

Comment: HI @juliomalves . Yes, I've tried that

Comment: You are referring to a webapp, so I am understanding that the "normal" login process is a browser flow. When you express the requirement to sign in with postman, are you attempting to play out the browser flow in postman? Or are you looking to use a more api driven authentication?

Comment: Hi @M.Gallant, i'm trying to use it for my mobile app

Answer (score 8):

You can sign in from the browser. Then get these cookies ( `next-auth.callback-url=value; next-auth.csrf-token=value; next-auth.session-token=value`) from the browser to use with the postman as `Cookie` header.

Comment: Just adding the next-auth.session-token was enough for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Next.js or NextAuth user myself, but looking at the signin page :
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/2469e44572f23f709fa8c5c65c6b7a4eb2383e9f/packages/next-auth/src/core/pages/signin.tsx

We can see that "credentials" type providers render a form that "POST" to the "callback" url.

```html
            {provider.type === "credentials" && (
              <form action={provider.callbackUrl} method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value={csrfToken} />
                {Object.keys(provider.credentials).map((credential) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={`input-group-${provider.id}`}>
                      <label
                        className="section-header"
                        htmlFor={`input-${credential}-for-${provider.id}-provider`}
                      >
                        {provider.credentials[credential].label ?? credential}
                      </label>
                      <input
                        name={credential}
                        id={`input-${credential}-for-${provider.id}-provider`}
                        type={provider.credentials[credential].type ?? "text"}
                        placeholder={
                          provider.credentials[credential].placeholder ?? ""
                        }
                        {...provider.credentials[credential]}
                      />
                    </div>
                  )
                })}
                <button type="submit">Sign in with {provider.name}</button>
              </form>
            )}
```

That form is expected to have a `csrfToken` which, if I understand this correctly, you can obtain yourself from `/api/auth/csrf` (https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthcsrf)

You should be able to inspect the rendered page to find out what the callback URL is for you, presumably `/api/auth/signin/:provider` but with the actual provider.

As for postman (or your mobile app), I expect that all you need to do is to POST to that URL. The request body will presumably need to be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` since the method is `POST`. Based on what I can understand from your question, the form should have 3 plain fields, `email`, `password` and `csrfToken`, but your `email` and `password` field names will be formatted as `input-${credential}-for-${provider.id}-provider`. Again, inspecting the rendered page and the network request will confirm the correct values.

Oh, and sorry for all the guesses. Hopefully there is still something useful in there.

Comment: I use next.js with next auth and can confirm all your guesses are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add **GET** endpoint to get CSRF token:

> {{url}}/api/auth/signin

Add Test to this endpoint at Postman with following code:

```js
console.log("Response: Test script");

pm.cookies.each(cookie => console.log(cookie));
let csrfToken = pm.cookies.get("next-auth.csrf-token");
// let csrfToken = pm.cookies.get("__Host-next-auth.csrf-token");
let csrfTokenValue = csrfToken.split('|')[0];
let sessionTokenValue = pm.cookies.get("next-auth.session-token");
// let sessionTokenValue = pm.cookies.get("__Secure-next-auth.session-token");

console.log('csrf token value: ', csrfTokenValue);
console.log('session token value: ', sessionTokenValue);

pm.environment.set("csrfToken", csrfTokenValue, "<your-environment-name>");
pm.environment.set("sessionToken", sessionTokenValue, "<your-environment-name>");
```

*"__Host-next-auth.csrf-token" and "__Secure-next-auth.session-token" I use to test Postman when deployed on Vercel.*

Add **POST** endpoint to Login and add the same test:

> {{url}}/api/auth/callback/credentials

First, you click on **GET** token, then **POST** login credentials payload. It will return HTML view, however it will set necessary cookies which makes you logged in.

To logout you need **POST** endpoint:

> {{url}}/api/auth/signout

Answer (score 1):

to add Sharukh Rahman answer, specifically go the Headers and in Key input Cookie then in Value input next-auth.session-token=value.